# Problems comparing char * to a string literal

Tags: c++, char

I am working on Go Fish for a class project. In this code I am trying to take in a face value of a card from the player and convert it into it's int number value (2 - 10, J=10, Q=11...)

```
    char valued[10];
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    cout << "What card would you like to ask " << _otherplayers[IndexOfPlayerChoice]->GetName() << " for? (2-10, J, Q, K, A) ";
    cin >> valued;
    int size = strlen(valued) +1;
    char * temp = new char[size];
    strcpy_s(temp, size, valued);

    if (temp == "J" || temp == "j")
        value = 11;
    if (temp == "Q" || temp == "q")
        value = 12;
    if (temp == "K" || temp == "k")
        value = 13;
    if (temp == "A" || temp == "a")
        value = 14;
    if (temp == "2" || temp == "3" || temp == "4" || temp == "5" || temp == "6" || temp == "7" || temp == "8" || temp == "9" || temp == "10")
        value = int(temp);
```

However when I run the code it never falls into any of the if statements. In the debugger it will show temp = "A" but when it gets to that if statement it will evaluate to false.

Any idea why this is occurring?

EDIT: Tried using strcmp like this

```
    if (strcmp(temp, "J") == 0 || strcmp(temp, "j") == 0)
        value = 11;
    if (strcmp(temp, "Q") == 0 || strcmp(temp, "q") == 0)
        value = 12;
    if (strcmp(temp, "K") == 0 || strcmp(temp, "k") == 0)
        value = 13;
    if (strcmp(temp, "A") == 0 || strcmp(temp, "a") == 0)
        value = 14;
    else
        value = int(*temp);
```

But strcmp says it has an error reading the string literal I'm comparing to.

Comment: You aren't using `std::string` n your code here, just `char*`?!? What's your question again please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ he is having trouble comparing the char * to a string literal

Comment: you can't compare strings with this `==` operator

Comment: You can add 'else's between the 'if's

Comment: @DamienBlack Aha! THX, wouldn't ever having guessed that without your help ;) ...

Comment: @OP `value = int(*temp);` This from your edit looks just plain wrong! You'll need some numeric text conversion operation here, e.g. like `atoi()`. And please specify any errors exactly in your post.

Comment: I quickly noticed this after posting and fixed it, thanks for the eye though!

Comment: @user3334986 _... and fixed it ..._ I don't see any fixes?!? Neither version of `value = int(temp);` you have will work as expected!

Comment: Are you delete[]-ing your temp variable after using it? Anyway, I do not see why are you dynamically allocating the temp buffer instead of using "valued" directly.

Answer (score 3):

`temp` is a pointer and, for example, `"J"` is an array of 2 `char` which can be converted to a pointer to its first element. So you are comparing two pointers. The comparison `temp == "J"` means, "Do the first characters in these two C-style strings have the same address?" The answer is no, they do not.

To compare C-style strings, you should use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). However, a more appropriate approach in C++ would be to use `std::string` instead of C-style strings.

Comment: The problem is we can't use strings in this class as they haven't been covered yet. Is there anyway I can tinker with this and get it to work without strings?

Comment: To clarify, `std::string` implements the comparison (==) operator, and it works as expected (value equality). Also, @user3334986 he told you how :p

Comment: @user3334986 You can use `strcmp` instead of `==`.

Comment: It always depresses me that these classes teach the hard and non-idiomatic way first.

Comment: Haha, duh, I'm sorry I read his comment too quickly. Thank you guys SO much for your exceptionally fast responses!

Comment: I tried using strcmp, edited the question with new code, and I get that strcmp has an error reading the string literals I'm trying to compare to.

Comment: @user3334986 What error?

Comment: It was just a problem with some of my if statements! Everything is working great now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
char * temp = new char[size];
strcpy_s(temp, size, valued);
```

With:

```
std::string temp(valued);
```

And it'll work a lot better - right now you're comparing string pointers, while `std::string` actually has an overload on operator `==` for comparison to C-style strings as you are attempting.

Comment: Or better yet, just declare `valued` as `std::string` in the first place and get rid of `temp`

Comment: Yeah well this is the quickest fix without rewriting *all* of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You arent't using strings (`std::string`) in your code sample anywhere! The right term for `"something"` in c++ is *'character array literal'*. Did you mean:

```
if (strcmp(temp,"J") == 0 // ...
```

Otherwise you're just comparing char pointers (`const char*`), whch are unlikely to match what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

== by default compares the address of the string, not the contents. You need to use something like strcmp

Comment: _'the address of the string'_ Of what string??

Comment: Sorry, by string I mean char *